Sum of iid random variables

Iid random variables $Y_1, Y_2, \dots, Y_{50}$ take only the values
$0$, $1$ and $2$ with probabilities $\mathbb{P}(Y_i = 0) =
\mathbb{P}(Y_i = 1) = \frac{4}{9}, \mathbb{P}(Y_i = 2) = \frac{1}{9}$.
Find the probability that the sum of these random variables will be
$45$.

Now here's my idea: let $i$ be the number of $2$'s ($i$ is an integer between $0$ and $22$), then we must have $45 - 2i$ $1$'s. There is $C^i_{50}$ ways to choose $Y_i$ that are gonna be equal to $2$ and $C^{45 - 2i}_{50 - i}$ ways to choose $Y_i$ that are gonna be equal to $1$. The rest are going to be $0$. Since we will have $i$ $2$'s, $45 - 2i$ $1$'s there is going to be $5 + i$ $0$'s (since we have $50$ variables in total).
Hence we have:
$$\sum \limits_{i = 0}^{22} C^i_{50} C^{45 - 2i}_{50 - i} \mathbb{P}(Y_i = 2)^{i} \mathbb{P}(Y_i = 1)^{45 - 2i} \mathbb{P}(Y_i = 0)^{5 + i} = $$
$$\sum \limits_{i = 0}^{22} C^i_{50} C^{45 - 2i}_{50 - i} (\frac{1}{9})^{i} (\frac{4}{9})^{45 - 2i} (\frac{4}{9})^{5 + i} = $$
$$(\frac{4}{9})^{45} (\frac{4}{9})^{5} \sum \limits_{i = 0}^{22} C^i_{50} C^{45 - 2i}_{50 - i} (\frac{1}{9})^{i} (\frac{4}{9})^{- 2i} (\frac{4}{9})^{i} = $$
$$(\frac{4}{9})^{50} \sum \limits_{i = 0}^{22} C^i_{50} C^{45 - 2i}_{50 - i}$$
Now what surprises me is that there are no probabilities left inside the sum. Am I doing everything correctly? And if so, how can I make this sum prettier (i.e. get a number instead of a sum)? Thanks!

This might be useful: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/228457326_Polynomial_coefficients_and_distribution_of_the_sum_of_discrete_uniform_variables

@RohitPandey That only applies to iid discrete uniform r.v.s, but maybe it'll give some ideas; e.g. I used generating functions to compute the answer here.

Use "pgf"s (Probability generating functions).
Here, any $X_i$ has the following pgf :
$$g(s)=\tfrac19(4+4s+s^2)$$
It is essential to note that
$$g(s)=\tfrac19(s+2)^2\tag{1}$$
The pgf of a sum of independent random variables is the product of their pgfs.
Therefore, it suffices to take (1) at the power $50$ and find in it the coefficient of $s^{45}$ by using the binomial formula.
It is interesting to plot the list of coefficients (which are the different probabilities) and see how "gaussian" it looks with a mean equal to the sum of the means of the $X_i$, i.e.,
$$50 \times \tfrac23 \approx 33.3$$

The histogram above has been plotted using the iteration of discrete convolution "conv" of Matlab :
 S=[1];
 for k=1:50
    S=conv([4,4,1]/9,S)
 end
 bar(0:(length(S)-1),S)


You beat me to it :). If I'm not mistaken, this gives $\binom{100}{45}{2^{55}\over 9^{50}}=737971498833254262266529255663310449944821760/171792506910670443678820376588540424234035840667=0.0042957...$

Thanks! Great answer!

@JeanMarie: Very nice and elegant presentation. (+1)

@Markus Scheuer Thanks, I have appreciated yours too because it shows indeed to ABlack that his approach was valuable, though not compact.

@ABlack's assumption that there should be probabilities in the final sum is correct. Here we show that @ABlack's approach is correct and leads to the same result as @JeanMarie's elegant answer. In the following we use the coefficient of operator $[z^k]$ to denote the coefficient of $z^k$ of a series. This way we can write for instance
\begin{align*}
[z^k](1+z)^n=\binom{n}{k}\tag{1}
\end{align*}

We obtain
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\sum_{i=0}^{22}}&\color{blue}{\binom{50}{i}\left(\frac{1}{9}\right)^i
\binom{50-i}{45-2i}\left(\frac{4}{9}\right)^{45-2i}\binom{5+i}{5+i}\left(\frac{4}{9}\right)^{5+i}}\\
&=\left(\frac{4}{9}\right)^{50}\sum_{i=0}^{22}\binom{50}{i}\binom{50-i}{45-2i}\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^i\\
&=\left(\frac{4}{9}\right)^{50}\sum_{i=0}^{50}\binom{50}{i}[z^{45-2i}](1+z)^{50-i}\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^i\tag{2}\\
&=\left(\frac{4}{9}\right)^{50}[z^{45}](1+z)^{50}\sum_{i=0}^{50}\binom{50}{i}\left(\frac{z^2}{4(1+z)}\right)^i\tag{3}\\
&=\left(\frac{4}{9}\right)^{50}[z^{45}](1+z)^{50}\left(1+\frac{z^2}{4(1+z)}\right)^{50}\tag{4}\\
&=\left(\frac{4}{9}\right)^{50}[z^{45}](1+z)^{50}\frac{(2+z)^{100}}{4^{50}(1+z)^{50}}\\
&=\left(\frac{1}{9}\right)^{50}[z^{45}](2+z)^{100}\tag{5}\\
&\,\,\color{blue}{=\frac{2^{55}}{9^{50}}\binom{100}{45}}
\end{align*}
in accordance with the answer from @JeanMarie.

Comment:

In (2) we use the coefficient of operator according to (1). We also set the upper limit of the sum to $50$ which does not change anything, since we are adding zeros only thanks to the coefficient of operator.

In (3) we apply the rule $[z^{p-q}]A(z)=[z^p]z^qA(z)$ and do some rearrangements.

In (4) we use the binomial theorem.

In (5) we select the coefficient of $z^{45}$.


